# Initializing a jagged array in c# gives index out of range exception

Tags: c#, arrays, exception, multidimensional-array, outofrangeexception

```
field = new int[input.Width][][];

for (int x = 0; x < input.Width; x++)
{
       field[x] = new int[input.Height][];

       for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
       {
           field[x][y] = new int[3];
       }
}
```

For some reason the above code is giving me out of range exception but the following works fine:

```
field = new int[input.Width][][];

for (int x = 0; x < input.Width; x++)
{
       field[x] = new int[input.Height][];

}

for (int y = 0; y < input.Height; y++)
{

       for (int x = 0; x < input.Width; x++)
       {
            field[x][y] = new int[3];                   

            field[x][y][0] = random.Next(0, output.Width);
            field[x][y][1] = random.Next(0, output.Height);
            field[x][y][2] = MaskFunctions.DSCALE;

        }
 }
```

Can anyone point out what am i doing wrong?

Also: Is there a difference between out of range and out of bound exception?

Comment: the first has `y < 3`, the second has `y < input.Height`.  Do those values differ?

Comment: @ps2goat yes they do! but you see its 4:30 am here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inner loop goes from `0` to `3`, instead of `0` to `input.Height`. This will produce an out of range exception when `input.Height < 3`.

You probably meant to do this:

```
field = new int[input.Width][][];

for (int x = 0; x < input.Width; x++)
{
       field[x] = new int[input.Height][];

       for (int y = 0; y < input.Height; y++)
       {
           field[x][y] = new int[3];
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked! can you also tell me if there is a difference between out of range and out of bound exception?

Comment: @AliZahid There's no difference, at least in this context. Some people just prefer to use different language. .NET calls it [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception.aspx) but Java calls it an an [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html). In either case, they mean essentially the same thing.